# How can I specify row order when I use dask.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have two dataframe with same shape.
I tried to convert to dask dataframe specifying same `n_partition=50`.
However, how each dataframe split into partition seems different as shown below image.
Does anyone know how I can specify how dataframe should be separated?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guess: the index values appear to be sorted, but one would be numerical and one lexicographical; i.e., I suspect that your dataframe `mrt_dask` has an index containing strings, not numbers. If this is so, then calling `astype` before passing it to dask should solve your issue, or perhaps you should change how it is being loaded in the first place.